# How does one invoke the errorHandler from async operations?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In using the [errorHandler](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/error-element) element, I am noticing that errors thrown from within Promises are not being handled.

**A sandbox reproducing the issue can be found: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-qer4jj?file=src%2FApp.tsx).**

In short, if you throw an error directly, the errorHandler is invoked:

```
function SyncError() {
  throw new Response('sync error', { status: 500 });
  return <p>You shouldn't see this</p>;
}
```

However, the error is thrown in a Promise, even if caught and rethrown, it is treated as unhandled:

```
function AsyncError() {
  Promise.reject(new Response('sync error', { status: 500 }))
    .catch((e) => {
      throw e;
    });
  return <p>You shouldn't see this</p>;
}
```

These are admittedly very contrived examples, but the actual behavior I'm trying to control is how to have the errors raised from within `useEffect` be caught by the `errorElement`. In other words, something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  someMethodThatThrows()
    .then(...)
    .catch((e) => {
      // What do I do?
    });
}, []);
```

I have a workaround in the sandbox above that involves setting local state to the error, but that seems pretty silly.

Is this a bug or the expected behavior? If expected behavior, are there any cleaner workarounds?

**UPDATE 10/10/2022**

After further review, it looks like this *is* expected behavior. Found this on the [react router site](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview#error-handling):

> The vast majority of your application errors are handled automatically
> by React Router. It will catch any errors that are thrown while:
>
> - rendering
> - loading data
> - updating data
>
> In practice, this is pretty much
> every error in your app except those thrown in event handlers (`<button onClick>`) or `useEffect`. React Router apps tend to have very few of
> either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand the `errorElement` works with the new Data API and works in conjunction with the `loader` handler.

In the case of your "async error" the error needs to be thrown when loading the route, not as an unexpected side-effect in the component *after* it's already been matched and rendered.

Example:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<Layout />} errorElement={<ErrorBoundary />}>
      <Route path="no-error" element={<NoError />} />
      <Route path="sync-error" element={<SyncError />} />
      <Route
        path="async-error"
        element={<AsyncError />}
        loader={async (props) => {
          // handle loading requests and throwing errors here
          console.log({ props });

          throw new Response('sync error', { status: 500 });
        }}
      />
      <Route path="async-error-hack" element={<AsyncErrorHack />} />
    </Route>
  )
);
```

...

```
function AsyncError() {
  // Not here
  // Promise.reject(new Response('sync error', { status: 500 })).catch((e) => {
  //   throw e;
  // });
  return <p>You shouldn't see this</p>;
}
```

If errors are being thrown or are occurring *after* the component has mounted then these should be handled gracefully in the component (*i.e. `try/catch`, etc...*) or by an actual [Error Boundary](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) component.

Comment: Thanks; the intended usage is starting to click. I just needed a paradigm shift. Included update above that the observed behavior (unable to capture exceptions in useEffect) is the expected behavior.